# Issue with Installation of Ruby & RVM; No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, rvm, ruby-install

Good afternoon,

I'm new at this and I think I did something wrong when trying to install Ruby with RVM. Here is what my terminal shows when I open it:

`Last login: Sun Oct 13 13:17:20 on ttys000`
`-bash: i[ -s /Users/<Username>/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]]: No such file or directory`
`Charless-MacBook-Pro-2:~ <Username>`

What steps should I take to remove the error message?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you please post what steps you took when installing rvm?

Answer (score 0):

In your .bashrc or .bash_profile it looks like you need to change the

```
[[ -s /Users/<Username>/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]]
```

to this :

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Or manually set the username   is a placeholder, you need to change that your username or set it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try the following steps.

First make sure you have the XCode Command Line Tools: 
You can add it by going to Xcode → Preferences
→ Downloads → Command Line Tools

Once you have it in your terminal try the following

```
$ curl -­L https://get.rvm.io | bash ­-s -stable
$ rvm get head && rvm reload
```

Now you want to make sure you have gcc­4.2 with

```
`which gcc­4.2`
```

You can now try to install Ruby

```
$ rvm install 2.0.0
$ rvm use 2.0.0 ­­default
```

if you'd like a pervious version you can also do:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3 # optional
```